# How do I preserve the data in my textfield when navigating to another tabview

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, tabs

How do I preserve my data when I navigate between two different tabs in Flutter... Basically what I want to achieve is, on one side of the tab, I see users data, and on the other side of the tab, I want to be able to copy some of those user data and paste into some textfields on the other tab without losing the data in the text fields when I navigate back and forth and still also preserving the level of scrolling I might have done on the tab where the users data show.

Comment: i think you should use a state management technique to keep the value across all widgets, take a look at [this](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html) This will ensure the State instance is not destroyed when leaving the screen.Extend your every tabview's state class with it and create an override method wannaKeepAlive and set it to true.Here is an example of a widget using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin.

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement wantKeepAlive
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Wow!thanks a lot worked perfectly as desired.. Really grateful